# Algolia Search typeahead implementation

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, algolia

I have an index on Algolia that have items like this one:

```
objectID: 1
name:"Universidade Estadual Paulista Júlio de Mesquita Filho"
acronym:"UNESP"
type:"level1"
aliases:[]
edited_by_admin:"1"
orderString:"UniversidadeEst..."
```

Almost all indexes have the **edited_by_admin** property as **"0"** and less than a half have this property set to "1".

I would like to know if there is a way to force the search using typeahead to search only over items that have the property **edited_by_admin** set to **"1"**.

I need this since users with certain permissions can only search on items with **edited_by_admin = 1** while admins can search over all results and I would like to use the same index for both.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer myself.

You have to set the property you want to filter as a facet on your index settings and then set it on typeahead like this:

```
$('...').typeahead(
{
  hint: false,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  source: index.ttAdapter({
    facetFilters: 'edited_by_admin:1',
    hitsPerPage: 100
  }),
  displayKey: 'name',
  templates: {
  ...
  }
});
```